# how to get user password in decrypted format

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I browse but didn't got proper solution.i am working on asp.net membership all i want to do is to retrieve user password when user apply for forgot password for condition 1. i want password to be in encrypted format in database and 2. retrieve password in decrypted format.is it possible.

Comment: It depends on the `encryption method` you use.

Comment: i am using windows authentication

Answer (score 1):

Normally, encrypted passwords would be stored using a one way hash. This means 
that the password cannot be decrypted once it is stored. Many authentication systems 
work by taking the password ( of the user trying to authenticate ), encrypting 
it using the same one way hash function as was used to store the password in the 
database, and then doing a string comparison in order to determine if the 
resulting encrypted password matches the one that exists in the database.

How are you determining if the user requesting the password  is actually 
the owner of the account ? Perhaps you can clarify your question with details 
of the environment so that we may offer alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PasswordRecoveryControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178335.aspx)

But anyhow it's not advisable to send password in plain text format.

Comment: It is also not advisable to save plain text format in database.That's the real scenario we are dealing with